# Angular view loses binding after text update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-bindings

I'am trying to use [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) to highlight text in elements rendered by Angular.

The problem i ran into was that the rendered text is updated by mark.js and Angular loses the reference to the updated text. The principes are shown in the example.

Minimal example: [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/XacFJ1H84bGgGyeijGrK?p=preview)

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-init="count=0">
    <p id="targetElement">Count: {{count}}</p>
    <p>
      <button ng-click="count = count + 1">Increase</button>
      <button onclick="targetElement.innerHTML='broken';">Break it</button>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to trigger a redraw after the text node is updated externally?

**Update**:

---

To make it more clear what the use case is:

[plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/vveZI2ge8A8Yv3Cn8Ric?p=preview)

```
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.10.0/mark.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-init="count=0">
    <p id="targetElement">{{count}}</p>
    <p>
      <button ng-click="count = count + 1">Increase</button>
      <button onclick="markInstance.markRegExp(/\d/);">Mark</button>
      <button onclick="markInstance.unmark();">Unmark</button>
    </p>
    <script>
      markInstance = new Mark(targetElement);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When you **mark & unmark** the text node inside `<p id="targetElement">` is replaced by mark.js. Angular will not render the view again. (It does update the text node no longer referenced by the DOM)

Comment: The rule behind binding concept is that you should never change html on your own, like you did in this example. If you need to change html of "targetElement" then don't bind any chiled html of it. Create it using some variable.

Comment: you just removed html having binding. Can you tell exactly why you changed that child html? Cause this is not your actual code.

Comment: I have updated the question to better explain the situation. Like i stated it is a problem with mark.js. It replaces a text node rendered by Angular. Angular doesn't notice this and still updates the text node which was replaced and no longer in the DOM.

Comment: sorry to disappoint you. But mark.js is manipulate html to highlight partial content. And angular will loose it's binding when that is done. You wont be able to use mark.js with angular. Either you need some thing compatible with angular or specifically create for angular.

Comment: There is no way to rebind or redraw that text node? (At this point i might even consider a dirty solution)

Comment: i have added plunker solution and posted answer please check if this can be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have don't have permission to update your plunker.  solution that will work for now is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jHdoq15bCHulLzKpHMDu?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with that is that the target element should be able to contain multiple (custom) directives that have bindings. Applying this solution would require to (deep) copy every element and all its children (the target element could be multiple pages long). I was going down the road of finding the scope of the updated text nodes and tell the owning scope to redraw or to bind to the new text node and update. Any experience with that? Thank you for your time so far anyway!

Comment: Sorry, won't be able to help you with that. I think you have to create something on your own using angular which fulfill purpose of mark.js. Best luck with that. Just remember that only one modifying DOM must be angular.